# nil error when attempting to set textfield placeholder, segment uiview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uisegmentedcontrol, uiview-hierarchy

xcode v:9.2

I am trying to load user information from the database to set as placeholder text. I have tested this code on a simpler project that does not have segment views, and it works fine. I did some research and I think it might be a hierarchical issue.  I am struggling to understand how I can make the textfield values load so that the locations they point to are connected when I try to access them and set placeholder values.

[GetCurr retrieves database values and sends them to completion handler function to write placeholder value. When run, "setPH = nil"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJsHP.png)

[Calls GetCurr for email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwcuq.png)

[Completion handler that sets placeholder text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEQPB.png)

[loadUserView should tell when to load the values of this particular segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1DWY.png)

[I know it's not my IBOutlets because they are all connected and as previously said, this code works perfectly fine in a simpler app that does not have segment views.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzU4c.png)

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Screenshots of code are not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I connected the segments to uiviews that had their own uiviewcontroller class, as subclasses of the parent base class. It also makes my code cleaner and prettier!

Useful:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html
https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/